# AspNetCore.Identity LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers Property

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to understand what the purpose of the `AllowedForNewUsers` property is for.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.allowedfornewusers?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=aspnetcore-2.1) states that it:

> Gets or sets a flag indicating whether a new user can be locked out. Defaults to true.

But this simply doesn't tell me anything of use, at face value it means that new users can be locked out but that's simply nonsensical since you already have the standard lockout feature.

I've even checked the [Git](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/pull/487/files) change log for when it was implemented but that was also of no help.

```
    /// Gets or sets a flag indicating whether users can be locked out after creation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// True if a newly created user can be locked out, otherwise false.
    /// </value>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Defaults to true.
    /// </remarks>
    public bool AllowedForNewUsers { get; set; } = true;
```

Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can see where the `AllowedForNewUsers` property is used in the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.1/src/Core/UserManager.cs#L475). This doesn't answer the question of *why* it exists though, which is why this is just a comment. :)

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking at the source.  Based on the original version (whether new users are locked out), this should mean whether new users are by default allowed however, when you read the description (and try follow the code) then it means "whether a newly created user can be locked out if they feed in an incorrect password".  But how long after creation is a new user "new" and when do they become old.  I tried to follow the code but it looks like I'll need to download the source as following it online gets quite complicated and I was hoping someone already knew the answer.

Comment: I did a little more searching and found [this](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/). I can see it being useful if you make lockouts an *opt-in* feature, I guess.

Comment: Did you understand what purpose it serves?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the "lock out on incorrect number of failed password attempts" is an opt-in per user, the value for `LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers` will cause the `IdentityUser<TKey>.LockoutEnabled` value to be set the same when creating a new user.

So if `LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers` is `true` then the `IdentityUser<TKey>.LockoutEnabled` will also be set to `true` and thus cause the user to be locked out after `LockoutOptions.MaxFailedAccessAttempts`.

- [IdentityUser.LockoutEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.lockoutenabled?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_IdentityUser_1_LockoutEnabled)
- [LockoutOptions.AllowedForNewUsers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.allowedfornewusers?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Identity_LockoutOptions_AllowedForNewUsers)
- [LockoutOptions.MaxFailedAccessAttempts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.maxfailedaccessattempts?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Thank you [Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) for posting the [link to this site](https://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/asp-net-identity-user-lockout/) which helps fill in a bunch of the blanks.